# stack image using index into loops in R

Tags: r, image, loops, stack, raster

I have 273 images in a folder and I would like to paste it into a matrix. I loaded the images using list.files and I created 2 loops for row and column of the matrix.

```
folder <- "C:/Users/Desktop/image"
jpeg <- list.files(folder, full.names=TRUE) 

#Size matrix
Number_R <- 13
Number_C <- 21
#create empty matrix
matrix <- matrix(, nrow = Number_R, ncol = Number_C)
total <- Number_R * Number_C

#i for row
#j for col
ind <- 0

for (i in (1:(Number_R))) {
  for (j in (1:(Number_C))) {
    ind <- ind+1
    l <-stack(ind)
    img_array <- as.array(l)
    }
  }
```

The problem is how to use the function stack in this case (if it is the right way)? For each iteration I would like to stack the image, l, that I loaded thanks to the function  "list.files". Finally I will have row 1/column 1 image 1; line 1/col 2 image 2; line 2/col 1 image 24; etc

I created an index name "ind" but I cannot use it with stack function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do

```
library(raster)
f <- list.files()
s <- stack(f)
m <- as.matrix(s)
```